# WOL (Wake On Lan) lights on card not showing after Ubuntu Server shutdown

Tags: networking, server

I'd like to enable WOL on my instance of Ubuntu server 18.04

I know the network card is capable of this as I have set it up in the BIOS and if I boot into a Windows 10 instance and shut the machine down, the WOL light flashes in the ethernet card jack.

However after I shutdown Ubuntu Server 18.04, the ethernet card jack shows not flashing lights for WOL.

In the windows setup I had to make sure that the ethernet card wasnt running in power saving mode but I do not know how to do this in Ubuntu Server for my card.

Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection I217-LM
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e

Thank you for the suggestions below.
The issue seems to be something to do with power saving mode on the ethernet adapter.  This is something that I can change in Windows 10 by going to properties and advanced and disabling 'Low power mode'.